# Safety of setting browser cookies from Express

Tags: express, cookies, jwt, mern, production

Recently deployed a site of mine, and I am wondering if this solution to allowing the Express server on Heroku to set browser cookies for my Netlify React app is safe. I found it on an ill-explained SO answer elsewhere.

```
                                User.create(req.body)
                                .then(userNew => {
                                    res
                                        .cookie(
                                            "usertoken",
                                            jwt.sign({ _id: userNew._id }, process.env.JWT_KEY),
                                            {
                                                secure: true,
                                                sameSite: "none",
                                                httpOnly: false,
                                            }
                                        )
                                        .json({
                                            msg: "User registration success!",
                                            user: {
                                                _id: userNew._id,
                                                userName: userNew.userName,
                                                email: userNew.email,
                                                favs: userNew.favs,
                                            }
                                        });
                                })
                                .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
```

The httpOnly, secure, and sameSite options are my concern. I used to only have httpOnly set to 'true' in development with no issue, but this solution worked for me in production. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set `httpOnly` to `true` to prevent client-side access to the cookie
- Make sure to set expiry for JWT with `expiresIn` option.
- Set `maxAge` in cookie option same at that of JWT expiry.
- You can track if you are in production or not with `NODE_ENV` environmental variable. You can set up your code in a way that you don't keep changing it during production and development.

Here is how I commonly use the cookie along with JWT

```js
  const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

  res.cookie(
    'usertoken',
    jwt.sign({ _id: userNew._id }, process.env.JWT_KEY, { expiresIn: '1d' }),
    {
      secure: isProd,
      sameSite: isProd ? 'none' : 'lax',
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    }
  );
```